# How do I call for two js files into a custom template?

Tags: javascript

I have a custom template where I've included a VC Post Grid but I'm figuring since it can't execute its js files I would call them myself except I don't know how.

The files are stored in my theme folder js. The files are imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js and vc_grid.min.js.

How do i make them load for my custom template page?

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's functions.php:

```
function my_theme_slug_enqueue_script(){
    if(is_page_template('path/to/template/relative/to/theme/directory/root/template_file.php')){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'some_unique_string_name', 'path/to/js/file/script.js', array(), false, true );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_slug_enqueue_script' );
```

Change the values in my snippet to your requirements (and you need to call `wp_enqueue_script()` twice, once for each of your JS files).

The third parameter allows you to tell WordPress what other scripts this script depends on (dependencies) and, if you put stuff in that array, then this script will be loaded AFTER those other scripts. The string(s) that you put into that array are the `handles` of those scripts (`handle` is the 'unique name'/the first parameter in the function).

E.g. `array('jquery')`.

The fourth parameter is the `version number`. You can either make it `false`, meaning no version number, or you can input an integer/float. This number will be appended to the URL to the asset, when loaded.

E.g. `1.0` will produce `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/script.js?ver=1.0`

The last parameter is where to place the asset. `false` to place it in the header (wherever you put `wp_head()`) and `true` to place it in the footer (wherever you put `wp_footer()`).

You may need to change the last 2 or 3 parameters of `wp_enqueue_script()` from that in my example, depending on your situation. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ for more info on `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Comment: Will try implement them, not even sure if it's gonna fix my problem but i'll definitely try and be back to report. Thank you for taking time to help.

Comment: This isn't right, is it?

`function my_theme_slug_enqueue_script(){
    if(is_page_template('http://www.blogfort.com/wp-content/themes/boss/bbpress.php')){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'vcgrid', 'http://www.blogfort.com/wp-content/themes/boss/js/vc_grid.min.js', array(), false, true );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_slug_enqueue_script' );`

Comment: And what do you mean with the last three parameters? I wouldn't know to which values to change them.

Comment: For the `is_page_template()` parameter, you need to pass the `path` relative to your theme root. So, for you it will be `'bbpress.php'`. Also, for the second argument in `wp_enqueue_script()` it needs to be the path, rather than the URL. Do it like this - `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/vc_grid.min.js'`

Comment: ... Change `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to `get_template_directory_uri()` if your theme is NOT a child theme.

Comment: Also, I would make the first parameter include the slug of your theme, to ensure unqiuness. e.g. - `'boss-vcgrid'`

Comment: And finally, I'm not too sure about the workings of bbpress, but I'm not sure that `bbpress.php` is a `template` in the sense of the way that it needs to be to work with `is_page_template()`, but give it a go.

Comment: See the new paragraph at the bottom of my answer for the meaning of the last 3 parameters